# Counting how many elements are in an interval in C

Tags: c, count, intervals

I'm given an interval (a,b) where a ≤ x ≤ b. a = -10 is given and b is entered by the user. I'm supposed to write a function count() in C that counts how many elements x are in this interval.

I got this to work but my approach is.. sketchy. I'm basically calculating b - a to get the number of elements and I'm adding 1 because of how the interval is defined. What I would like to know is if there's a better way of doing this.. one that actually counts the elements.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define LIMIT -10

int count(int a, int b);

int main() {
    int x;

    printf("Enter a number:");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    printf("count(%d, %d) = %d", LIMIT, x, count(LIMIT, x));
}

int count(int a, int b) {
    if (b >= a)
        return (b - a) + 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: *better*, *...one that actually counts*  - these two are contradicting.

Comment: A subtraction is not "counting". While I agree it would be the way to go, your assigmnent might require a loop. As a side-fact: A good compiler might end up doing the subtraction, eliminating the loop. But that's an implementation detail.

Comment: Shouldn't the `else` be `else return 0;`? And computing is usually more efficient than counting. Suppose `b` is `INT_MAX`... ?

Comment: possible bug: `if (b >= LIMIT)` should be `if (b >= a)`

Comment: It's supposed to "count" down too.. so (-10, -15) would be 6 elements. I had to put in that else statement because otherwise it would have been -6. Again.. probably not the way to go but at least it produces the right output.

Comment: @Weather Vane  is right, you said `where a ≤ x ≤ b. a = -10` so `b` cannot be less than `a`

Comment: I changed it to return 0, that's probably how it was meant!

Comment: Isn't anyone going to comment on "int main() "  ??

Comment: @nicomp is anything wrong with it?

Comment: @Dennis are you sure you're required to actually count, rather than just return the count? i.e. do the verb vs return the noun. If both give the same result why not do the more efficient one?

Comment: @Kevin The assignment uses the verb "count" so I assume using a loop with a counter is the way to go. Although I might as well present both.

Comment: @Kevin Well, some would say so...

Comment: @nicomp Care to elaborate?

Comment: @Kevin int main(void)   ... I, for one, couldn't care less and I am teasing because inevitably someone picks at that issue like a scab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a counter variable, that is initialized with zero, and increment inside the for loop from start_limit to end_limit & just return it.

```
function count(int a, int b)     
{
int count=0;                                      //determines how many elements in interval
for(int i=start_limit ; i<=end_limit ;i++)      //here, start_limit=a , end_limit=b
{ 
count++;                                
}
return count;                                   //it returns total no. of elements inside interval
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But I'm sure you meant to use a for-loop, not a while-loop.

Comment: Yes, I adjusted it and it works as intended now. Thanks again!

Comment: @Dennis  it's my pleasure .. :)